# address an object by retrieving the ID name of the object from a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Good evening,

I am trying to get the following done. I have seen a similar post but it was related with Unity.

Anyway, I am on web forms in asp.net and I have a radiobuttonList with ID="id001"

so on my code behind, I would normally be able to get the selected value by just doing:

```
string value = id001.SelectedValue
```

However, in this situation, I don't know the exact ID name, so I have a function that retrieves it. So now I have the variable with the name of the ID. So I want to be able to now, convert the value of that variable in something like this:

```
string foundid = "id001"

string foundidvalue = id001.SelectedValue
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: code of the function that retrieves ID? Your radiobuttonlist are inside a GridView, ListView, Repeater?
if you can not pass this information, use the HelloWord solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this one is related to your previous question. So, when you found the control, instead of using function to get the fullname, you can do like this:

```
     foreach (Control c in Page.Form.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>())
        {

            if (c.ID.Contains("id"))
            {
               // string FullID = c.ID.ToString();
                var radioButtonList = c as RadioButtonList; 
                var selectedValue = radioButtonList.SelectedValue;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use FindControl.

```
string foundid = "id001";
var foundCtrl = (RadiobuttonList)FindControl(foundid);
var result = foundCtrl.SelectedValue;
```